# Как правильно считывать данные из стандартного входного потока JS?

Tags: javascript, input

Есть задача, которую я решил, но ее нужно проверить через форму на Stepik. Я не знаю как получить данные из "стандартного входного потока" для javascript.

Вот что написано в задаче:
На вход подаётся температура на улице в целых градусах в диапазоне от -50 до +50.
Данные следует считывать из стандартного входного потока, например для Питона так:
x = int(input())

Соответственно для других языков надо написать получение данных самому.
Вот что я пробовал:

```
const x=+prompt(); // не работает
switch(true) {
    case (x >= -26 && x <= -1): {
        result='холодно';
        break;
    }
    case (x >= 0 && x <= 10): {
        result='прохладно';
        break;
    }
    case (x >= 11 && x <= 25): {
        result='тепло';
        break;
    }
    case (x > 25): {
        result='жара';
        break;
    }
    default: {
        result='жутко холодно';
        break;
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что еще можно попробовать?

Comment: Речь идет о каком окружении? Сервер? Браузер?

Comment: Используйте встроенный модуль `readline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предположить что вы работаете с nodejs и от вас хотят чтение [`stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

```
process.stdin.addListener("data", function(data) {
    let x = Number(data.toString().trim()) || 0;

    console.log(`x: ${x}`);

    process.stdin.pause();
});
```